# how to calculate bitwise OR using AND, XOR and shift?

Tags: bit-manipulation

The question seems pretty well formulated

I have a virtual machine which implements only AND, XOR, SHL and SHR, yet I have to do a "OR 0x01" operation.

Comment: sounds like a homework question

Comment: I don't need a solution, only an idea at least. It is a homework, but frankly I'm already doing more than I need to solve the problem. For instance, I've invented a calling convention to better modularize my code. So the question itself is not the homework per se, only something I need to know.

@KennyTM:it's a 16-bit machine

Comment: @KennyTM:it's a 16-bit machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all having a correct bitwise computation for the following two variables is sufficient, because they cover all combinations:
A=0101
B=0011

We want
0101
0011
A or B
0111

for xor we get

0101
0011
A xor B
0110

for and we get

0101
0011
A and B
0001

so if we connect them with an xor we are done.

(A xor B) xor (A and B)

Answer (score 2):

I would just start with

```
a xor b = ((not a) and b) or (a and (not b))
```

and unleash some boolean algebra on that until it looks like

```
a or b = <expression using only and, xor>
```

Admittedly, this is probably more work to actually do than going the "try every conceivable bit combination" route, but then you did ask for homework solution ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

The truth table as summarized on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and gasp, basic CS 101 stuff, [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)....

```
AND
0 & 0   0
0 & 1   0
1 & 0   0
1 & 1   1


OR
0 | 0   0
0 | 1   1
1 | 0   1
0 | 0   1


XOR
0 ^ 0   0
0 ^ 1   1
1 ^ 0   1
1 ^ 1   0
```

A Shift Left involves shifting the bits across from right to left, suppose:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0| = 0x4 hexadecimal or 4 decimal or 100 in binary
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Shift Left by 2 places becomes
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0| = 0x10 hexadecimal or 16 decimal or 10000 in binary
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Shift Right by 1 places becomes
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0| = 0x8 hexadecimal or 8 decimal or 1000 in binary
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Then it is a matter of combining the bit-wise operations according to the truth table above...

Answer (score 0):

I would just expand [DeMorgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `A or B = not(not A and not B)`.  You can compute `not` by XORing with all 1 bits.